# Change -webkit-transition-delay with jquery

Tags: jquery, webkit, delay, jquery-isotope

I am currently setting my delay here:

```
.isotope .isotope-item {
    -webkit-transition-property: left, top, opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: left, top, opacity;
    -ms-transition-property: left, top, opacity;
    -o-transition-property: left, top, opacity;
    transition-property: left, top, opacity;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.8s, 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s, 0.8s, 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s, 0.8s, 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s, 0.8s, 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0.8s, 0s;
}
```

I have a conditional statement in jQuery and need to be able to change my delay like so:

```
.isotope .isotope-item {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s, 0.8s, 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 2s, 0.8s, 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 2s, 0.8s, 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 2s, 0.8s, 0s;
    transition-delay: 2s, 0.8s, 0s;
}
```

Any ideas if this is possible to accomplish or any other solutions to solve this??

Comment: I think you should have tried something before asking. Didn't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your condition, add another class to the elements which need the longer delay, for example `foo`, then change your second style to this:

```
.isotope .isotope-item.foo {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s, 0.8s, 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 2s, 0.8s, 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 2s, 0.8s, 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 2s, 0.8s, 0s;
    transition-delay: 2s, 0.8s, 0s;
}
```

The higher specificity will ensure those elements receive the longer delay time.

Comment: Probably the cleanest way to do it

Answer (score 4):

jQuery can deal with vendor prefixes just fine.

```
$(".isotope-item").css('-webkit-transition-delay', '2s, 0.8s, 0s' )
   .css('-moz-transition-delay', '2s, 0.8s, 0s')
   .css('-ms-transition-delay', '2s, 0.8s, 0s')
   .css('-o-transition-delay', '2s, 0.8s, 0s')
   .css('transition-delay', '2s, 0.8s, 0s');
```

will work if you don't want to add a new class like Rory suggested.

http://jsfiddle.net/qzuDr/